# BigQuery average time with gap constraint

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table representing messages, every message belongs to a conversation and has a date:

```
conversation    date    
1               2018-06-22 23:16:46.456 UTC
2               2018-06-05 00:07:12.178 UTC
1               2018-06-22 23:16:46.456 UTC
4               2018-06-05 00:07:12.178 UTC
3               2018-06-22 23:51:28.540 UTC
3               2018-06-23 00:02:59.285 UTC
4               2018-06-04 23:21:59.500 UTC
```

I need to get the average time spent in a conversation

I used this query to get it:

```
SELECT conversation, timestamp_diff(MAX(date), MIN(date), MINUTE) minutes
FROM `Message`
GROUP BY conversation
```

But since some conversations take several days, they have to be cut into smaller chunks when a the gap between messages is larger than 1 hour example:

```
conversation    date    
2               2018-06-22 00:01:46.456 UTC   # group 1
2               2018-06-22 00:07:12.178 UTC   # group 1
2               2018-06-22 00:16:46.456 UTC   # group 1
2               2018-06-22 01:07:42.178 UTC   # group 1
      there is a gap here
2               2018-06-22 12:51:28.540 UTC   # group 2
2               2018-06-22 13:00:40.486 UTC   # group 2
      there is another gap here
2               2018-06-22 19:54:30.031 UTC   # group 3
```

I think this is possible using Analytic Functions:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts

But I didn't figure out how to do it, any help would be really appriciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Is it to calculate some sort of average?  Or is it to break up long conversations into shorter ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

> they have to be cut into smaller chunks when a the gap between messages is larger than 1 hour:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 2 conversation, TIMESTAMP '2018-06-22 00:01:46.456 UTC' dt UNION ALL   # group 1
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 00:07:12.178 UTC' UNION ALL   # group 1
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 00:16:46.456 UTC' UNION ALL   # group 1
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 01:07:42.178 UTC' UNION ALL   # group 1
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 12:51:28.540 UTC' UNION ALL   # group 2
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 13:00:40.486 UTC' UNION ALL   # group 2
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 19:54:30.031 UTC'             # group 3
), conversation_groups AS (
  SELECT 
    conversation, dt, 
    SUM(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY conversation ORDER BY dt) conversation_group
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      conversation, dt, 
      SIGN(IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dt, LAG(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY conversation ORDER BY dt), HOUR), 0)) flag
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
SELECT *
FROM conversation_groups
ORDER BY conversation, dt
```

with result as

```
Row conversation    dt                              conversation_group   
1   2               2018-06-22 00:01:46.456 UTC     0    
2   2               2018-06-22 00:07:12.178 UTC     0    
3   2               2018-06-22 00:16:46.456 UTC     0    
4   2               2018-06-22 01:07:42.178 UTC     0    
5   2               2018-06-22 12:51:28.540 UTC     1    
6   2               2018-06-22 13:00:40.486 UTC     1    
7   2               2018-06-22 19:54:30.031 UTC     2
```

> I need to get the average time spent in a conversation

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 2 conversation, TIMESTAMP '2018-06-22 00:01:46.456 UTC' dt UNION ALL   # group 1
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 00:07:12.178 UTC' UNION ALL   # group 1
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 00:16:46.456 UTC' UNION ALL   # group 1
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 01:07:42.178 UTC' UNION ALL   # group 1
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 12:51:28.540 UTC' UNION ALL   # group 2
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 13:00:40.486 UTC' UNION ALL   # group 2
  SELECT 2, '2018-06-22 19:54:30.031 UTC'             # group 3
), conversation_groups AS (
  SELECT 
    conversation, dt, 
    SUM(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY conversation ORDER BY dt) conversation_group
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      conversation, dt, 
      SIGN(IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dt, LAG(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY conversation ORDER BY dt), HOUR), 0)) flag
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
SELECT conversation, AVG(IF(duration = 0, NULL, duration)) avg_duration
FROM (
  SELECT
    conversation, conversation_group,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(dt), MIN(dt), MINUTE) duration
  FROM conversation_groups
  GROUP BY conversation, conversation_group
)
GROUP BY conversation
ORDER BY conversation
```

with result as

```
Row conversation    avg_duration     
1   2               37.0
```

Note: you can adjust logic of calculating avg based on your particular needs/vision of how to do so - but the way it is done above is - first duration of each group is calculated and then average of duration in these groups are taken - and note: if there is  a duration of zero it is replaced with NULL so it does not affect average calculation. Duration is calculated in MINUTEs, but you can go with SECONDs or whatever you need